# global auto-incrementing field in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to create a globally auto-incrementing value in a collection?

Perforce has the concept of a changelist# that can be a powerful feature for stateless updates. I am thinking of the same type of functionality.

Example:

```
create> DocA.name = "foo" => changelist = 1
create> DocB.name = "bar" => changelist = 2
update> DocA.name = "bob" => changelist = 3
create> DocC.name = "joe" => changelist = 4
```

Results:

```
DocA.changelist = 3
DocB.changelist = 2
DocC.changelist = 4
```

Then I can search for any changes made after changelist:4 and be confident I did not miss anything.

Any thoughts from the mongodb gurus on how to do that efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB docs have a listing for [auto-incrementing fields](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field). In general it is bad practice, but this could work for the functionality you seek.

That stated, I have also seen people use "timestamps" for the last updated time. This may satisfy your requirements.

Likewise, if this is a really key feature, you may want to look at Riak's MVCC which seems closest to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Timestamps always have a problem of potential collisions down to the microsecond which becomes a problem for us. However, it occurred to me we could use a secondary collection to $INC a counter that is appended to a timestamp. That auto-incrementing field article looked rather... ugly.

Comment: hmmm, it almost sounds like you need some form of MVCC... don't know how married you are to MongoDB yet, you may want to look at Riak... as to the auto-increment article, it's not great simply because it's not recommended

Comment: I see what you mean about Riak, but I think it still does not provide an ever increasing numeric value. By having an increasing "changelist", it makes it simple to find what changed in a collection since I last checked. The vclock is hash based and appears more for update and sync conflict resolution.